# Learning CSS, encountering problems with vertical borders

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm trying to add a left border to my article section that I've floated to the right. Unfortunately i'm a beginner in every sense of the word and finally after 10 plus hours I figure I should seek help.

This is the example that I'm trying to emulate in my code and its a solid border connecting the top and bottom borders. I was able to figure top and bottom out easily enough.

and the code that I've been able to figure out that get me the closest is

```
article {
   float: right;
   width: 52%;
   background-color: peachpuff;
}
article h2 {
   border-left: 3px solid red;
   }
article h3 {
   border-left: 3px solid red;
   }
article p {
   border-left: 3px solid red;
   }
aside {
   float: left;
   width: 38%
}
```

However, it still leaves separation between each element. I know this should be something basic as it is simple formatting but like I said I'm a complete beginner. Thanks in advance for the help everyone!

Comment: Please provide the html markup, or a link to a js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is your page...You shouldn't try and combine multiple borders to make one long one. There is probably an easier way to do it. i.e. Wrap it all in another div that has the border element. For reference though the gap is the auto margin `<h>` tags have. You could have made `margin:0;` for all of those elements but that is more of a hacky way to do it. (Padding however does add the border to it)

You can always right click "Inspect" anything you want to investigate. Get very familiar with the inspector because it is a god send for developing HTML/CSS.

```css
.article {
   float: right;
   width: 52%;
   background-color: peachpuff;
}

.contentBorder{
   border-left: 3px solid red;
}

.aside {
   float: left;
   width: 38%
}
```

```html
<div class="aside">
  here is my side content
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="contentBorder">
    <h2>My Header 2</h2>
    <h3>My Header 3</h3>  
    <p>Hello here is my content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! With your suggestion I was able to figure it out enough to get what I needed done. I didn't even think about the inspect option so thanks for the reminder. You have also given me a list of new things to look into with how the div wrapping works.

Answer (score 0):

If the first guys suggestion doesn't work then check to make sure that all your `<p>,<h1>,<h2>` tags dont have margins - they always do by default. If they do, but you still want a certain spacing between them, use padding on each individual element instead - an elements border doesn't follow along it's margin.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! It turned out it was the margins after all.